# Calling a matrix from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I created a dictionary `m` of 3 10x10 matrices

and I wanted to print something if `AB(C)==(AB)C` so

```
if (m[0]@m[1])@m[2]==m[0]@(m[1]@m[2]):
    print("yes!")
else:
    print("no...")
```

This is returning `KeyError:0`

If I also define each key `a,b`, and `c` respectively, and do this

```
if ((a@b)@c)==(a@(b@c)):
```

I get `a is not defined`...

Any help will be much appreciated!

Edit: Language is Python...sorry first post

Comment: Prog language is...?

Comment: @Tarik python sorry...

Comment: numpy matrix?....

Comment: Print the content of the dictionary m

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

if np.matmul(np.matmul(m[0],m[1]),m[2]) == np.matmul(m[0],np.matmul(m[1],m[2])):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: I am assuming m is an ordered dictionary